# Outlook email To field reference in access

Tags: ms-access

I got the code below from a post here but I made a modification to send an email to the resulting list. The issue I am having is that when I put the "To" information to send the email I am getting an error.

```
'code for sending outlook email as a reminder 
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Table1 where Table1.Fieldx = ""No"" and (Date() +3 > Table1.duedate)")
    
'checking if the recordset has data
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
            
        Dim Msg As String
        Msg = "Dear " & Forms!FormSample.AssignTo & ",<P>" & _
        "An email will be sent in 2 days (" & (Date + 2) & ").<P>" & _
        "Regards, "
    
        Dim O As Outlook.Application
        Dim M As Outlook.MailItem
        
        Set O = New Outlook.Application
        Set M = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        
        With M
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .HTMLBody = Msg
            .To = Table1.Email2   'this email is a field in Table1
            .Subject = "Testing access sending auto email " & Now()
            .Send
        End With
        Set M = Nothing
        Set O = Nothing
    Loop
    
Else
MsgBox "there are no records in the recordset"

End If
```

The error is Run-Time error '424' Object required and it is highlighting .To = Table1.email2.

Can anyone help me? I am just trying to send the email to the list I get from the select in the Currentdb.OpenRecordset.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Can't pull data from a table or query like that. If you want to send one email to a multi-address **To** list, that usually requires looping through a recordset or multi-select listbox to build semi-colon separated list. Exactly what is in email2 field - a single address? If you want to send email to a single address: `.To = rs!email2`.

Comment: Add `rs.MoveNext` to a new line just before `Loop`  ... without it, you will remain on the first record each loop through the recordset.

Comment: Should declare and set the Outlook.Application object outside the loop. Best practice is to declare all variables at beginning of procedure. Set object variables when needed. @HansUp made a good catch on the rs.MoveNext - without it you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your input. i was able to get it right. yes, June7 was right, i only need it to change table1 for rs! and it worked. Hansup, my loop was infinite, thank you for your catch.